# Getting gallery.scrollGallery is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do the horizontal scroll on one of my page but i am getting an error of gallery.scrollGallery is not a function.

can anyone suggest me how it needs to be solved.

the code below is:

```
gallery.scrollGallery({
    mask: '.mask',
    slider: '.slideset',
    slides: '.slide',
    generatePagination: '.paging',
    pagerLinks: '',
    autoRotation: true,
    step: 1,
    switchTime: 3000,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    onInit: function(self) {
        var pagination = jQuery(self.options.generatePagination).find('li');

        win.on('load resize scroll orientationchange', function() {
            currentSlide = self.currentStep;
            if (gallery.hasClass(viewportClass)) {
                jQuery(pagination[currentSlide]).addClass(activeClass);
                self.resumeRotation();
            } else {
                jQuery(pagination[currentSlide]).removeClass(activeClass);
                self.pauseRotation();
            }
        });
    },
    onBeforeChange: function(self) {
        var pagination = jQuery(self.options.generatePagination).find('li');

        for (var i = 0; i < pagination.length; i++) {
            var currSlide = jQuery(pagination[i]);

            if (i < self.currentStep) {
                currSlide.addClass(passedClass);
            } else {
                currSlide.removeClass(passedClass);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please share some code, What can we understand from your question without code?!

Comment: Are you using a third party component? In addition what's your `gallery` variable and how you get it via DOM?